# How do I reference WindowedApplication from inside a class I made?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

I'm using Flex 4.5, and I have imported a custom class I wrote into the main MXML file.

Inside the class file, I want to be able to create a `TitleWindow` using the `PopUpManager` like this:

```
package classes {
    import components.*; // My custom components
    import mx.managers.PopUpManager;

    public class SomeClass {
        public function showPopUp():void {
            PopUpManager.createPopUp(this,NewProjectPrompt,true);
        }
    }
}
```

`NewProjectPrompt` is a custom component I made. The compiler is giving me the following error:

```
1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type classes:Project to an unrelated type flash.display:DisplayObject.
```

This is because `this` isn't pointing at `WindowedApplication`. How do I make the first parameter in `.createPopUp()` point to the `WindowedApplication`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this code works!

public function showPopUp(){ 
   PopUpManager.createPopUp(FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication as DisplayObject,NewProjectPrompt,true);
}

Comment: Thank you!! This worked great. :D
However, as a friendly suggestion, it would have been nice if you had explained a bit further. I found a nice article on Adobe's site that explains what you're saying in detail (for anyone else who has this same question): http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7e3a.html

Answer (score 1):

If your WindowedApplication file is named "MyApp.mxml" then you would write a reference from a component to it like this:

```
MyApp(this.parentApplication)
```

This will return the actual WindowedApplication and you can call its public methods or stick it in a variable if need be.

Comment: I tried this, but Flex 4.5 doesn't recognize `parentApplication`. The closest match was `parentObject` but it didn't work.

Comment: You can use a variable like this `var myApp:MyApp = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication as MyApp;` if you need to access it as the WindowedApplication with your top level methods available.